# Heading mixing/floating next to paragraph

Tags: html, css

Trying to do a school project and doing several headings to make the text after the paragraphs stand out but the secondheading keeps mixing in with the first paragraphs under heading 1

```
<h1>Nvidia</h1>
    <p>For more than two decades, NVIDIA has pioneered visual computing, the art and science of computer graphics.
    </p>
    <p>With a singular focus on this field, they offer specialized platforms for the gaming, professional visualization, data center and automotive markets.
    </p>
    <p>Their work is at the center of the most consequential mega-trends in technology - virtual reality, artificial intelligence and self-driving cars.
    </p>   


    <h2>THE WORLD LEADER IN VISUAL COMPUTING</h2>
       <p>NVIDIA  are vertically integrated and bring together GPUs, system  software, algorithms, systems and services to create unique value for the  markets They serve.</p>
    p {
font-family: "Calibri";
margin: 10px 10px 2px 10px;
float: left;
font-size: 140%;
color:ghostwhite;
}

h2 {
text-align: center;
font-family: Calibri;
color: #76b900;
margin: 3%;
}

h1 {
color: #76b900;
text-align: center;
font-family: "Calibri";
margin: 3%;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but it's not clear what you're having trouble with. What is it that you want to do that you're having trouble with?

Comment: Im new to css and html so it's hard to explain my problem so I'm sorry about that.
Basically I want to make one heading followed by a paragraph under it, then under that paragraph another heading and another paragraph followed under it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Basically I want to make one heading followed by a paragraph under it, then under that paragraph another heading and another paragraph followed under it

Just remove the `float` from the paragraphs.

```css
p {
  font-family: "Calibri";
  margin: 10px 10px 2px 10px;
  font-size: 140%;
  color: grey;
}
h2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Calibri;
  color: #76b900;
  margin: 3%;
}
h1 {
  color: #76b900;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Calibri";
  margin: 3%;
}
```

```html
<h1>Nvidia</h1>
<p>For more than two decades, NVIDIA has pioneered visual computing, the art and science of computer graphics.
</p>
<p>With a singular focus on this field, they offer specialized platforms for the gaming, professional visualization, data center and automotive markets.
</p>
<p>Their work is at the center of the most consequential mega-trends in technology - virtual reality, artificial intelligence and self-driving cars.
</p>


<h2>THE WORLD LEADER IN VISUAL COMPUTING</h2>
<p>NVIDIA are vertically integrated and bring together GPUs, system software, algorithms, systems and services to create unique value for the markets They serve.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can take a look at bootstrap. It is easy to learn. If you want to show these parts underneath eachother you can just write:

```
<div class="row">
  <h1>...</h1>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <p>...</p>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <h2>...</h2>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <p>...</p>
</div>
```

http://getbootstrap.com/